# how to display string tokenizer result in Jlabels in java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How do I display result of `StringTokenizer` object into `JLabel`s? I have few tokens after I tokenize this: `test1$test2$test3$`

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, "$");

while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

, which results in

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I want each token to be in different `JLabel` on a scroll panel. Result count after tokenize here is 3 but it can change so it can be 5, 20 or 25. How to do it dynamically ? thank you

Comment: @user1329572 I haven't anything, I'm newbie in java I'm still learning, but so far i thought to add those tokens to some array then count those array elements (added tokens) and then create so many JLabels how much array size is and put those elemenst from array to that Jlabels but i dont know how to do it exactly, some code would be nice

Comment: This site is not a code generator. Here are some [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, "$");

while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
 labels.add(new JLabel(tokenizer.nextToken()));
}

JPanel p = new JPanel();
for(int =0; i<labels.size(); i++)
{
 p.add(labels.get(i));
}
...
```

See here for [Beginner guide to Java Swing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-intswing/).

Comment: thank you, just one more question, because I have implemented it and in arrayList it adds those 3 elements when I print labels.size() but it doesnt display them on panel. how do i setBounds for those labels to display 1 under another and so on. Something like labels.add(new JLabel(tokenizer.nextToken()).setBounds(30, 50+10*i, 210, 14); ?

Comment: Use a JPanel BorderLayout say GridLayout to control the locations on JPanel to which you want the labels to be. The default is FlowLayout which will add the labels in a continous flow on the panel.

Comment: Also consider `for (JLabel label : labels) { p.add(label) }`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the tokens into an `ArrayList` and offer the user a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) instead.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.  E.G.

[image: JList demo.]